# Who first proved the fundamental theorem of finitely generated (or finite) abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, math-history

The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups (or maybe just finite abelian groups) is well-known and can be found in just about any text on the theory of groups or abstract algebra.  Any finitely generated abelian group $A$ has a primary decomposition:
$$A \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{n}\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^{m}\mathbb{Z}_{q_{k}} ,$$
in which the $q_{k}$ are prime powers.
It also has an invariant factor decomposition:
$$A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^{s}\mathbb{Z}_{f_{k}},$$
in which $f_{1}\mid f_{2}\mid\cdots\mid f_{s}$.

> My question is: Who first proved these results?

I looked at several standard texts, and a bunch of online results, but I found only a confused indication of who first established these.  Both Robinson and Rotman indicate that the primary decomposition is due to Frobenius-Stickelberger, but might (in part?) date back to Gauss, while some online sources (e.g.,
[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDecompositionTheorem.html),
usually fairly reliable) call it a Kronecker decomposition, suggesting perhaps a different history. I did not see any indication of who proved the invariant factor decomposition, or which (if not worked out simultaneously) came first.

Comment: Well I could find the proof here but don't know who proved it: http://math.arizona.edu/~savitt/teaching/07math511a/fin_gen_ab_gps.pdf

Comment: The results are basic enough so that it could have occurred to many people before the concept of an abelian group was firmly established. Something like a higher dimensional Chinese remainder theorem? Therefore planting a flag on them may be somewhat pointless. Certainly at the time the listed people were working on related themes they had moved on to deeper stuff.

Answer (score 7):

The book *Abelian groups* by Fuchs claims that the Fundamental Theorem for Finite Abelain Groups (which Fuchs calls the *Basis Theorem*) is due to [Frobenius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Georg_Frobenius) and Ludwig Stickelberger (1850-1936, a colleague of Frobenius from Zurich). See also *A course in the Theory of Groups* by Robinson. However, neither book attributes the more general finitely-generated case to anyone.

The cited paper is the following.

> G. Frobenius, L. Stickelberger, *[Uber Gruppen von vertauschbaren Elementen](https://eudml.org/doc/148395)*, J. reine u. angew. Math., **86** (1878), 217-262.

[MacTutor](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Frobenius.html) claims that this paper gives a proof of the more general structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. As I do not speak German, I would struggle to verify this. Therefore, I would tend to believe Fuchs and Robinson, and attribute the MacTutor claim to (a very understandable) human error.

Comment: The paper is available here: https://eudml.org/doc/148395

Comment: Thanks very much. Alas, I also do not read German.

Comment: As a speaker of German, I can confirm the paper proves the theorem for finite groups, and it seems not to contain any material on non-finite groups.